# given a set of coordinate points, how do i find the outer circle?

Tags: java

I have a project where I have a set of coordinates of a city and I need to find the most middle point of the set.

In order to do that I thought it would be helpful to have a list of all points forming the "outer circle" like that:

[outer circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IvOL.png)

How would I do something like that?

Comment: Have you thought about trying to find the points with in min x/y and max x/y? This would at least give you a bounding rectangle - you can either create a circle or ellipse from that if you really wanted to or just calculate the center of the rectangle and find the nearest point(s)

Comment: that's what I thought about as well. I need to figure out how to find those points now, thanks!